# Не работает radial-gradient safari

Tags: css

Версия 5

```css
.ticket {
  /* Style for "btn" */
  width: 279px;
  height: 65px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 31px;
  -moz-border-radius: 31px;
  border-radius: 31px;
  background-image:  -o-linear-gradient( top, #004ea3 0%, #2d91ff 99%, #2d91ff 100%), -o-linear-gradient(top, #242b47 0%, #181d33 100%);
  background-image:  -webkit-linear-gradient( top, #004ea3 0%, #2d91ff 99%, #2d91ff 100%), -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #242b47 0%, #181d33 100%);
  background-image:  -moz-linear-gradient( top, #004ea3 0%, #2d91ff 99%, #2d91ff 100%), -moz-linear-gradient(top, #242b47 0%, #181d33 100%);
  background-image: linear-gradient( top, #004ea3 0%, #2d91ff 99%, #2d91ff 100%), linear-gradient( top, #242b47 0%, #181d33 100%);
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
}
.ticket:hover {
  background-image: -o-radial-gradient(circle 232px at 56.15% 56.93%, #2d91ff 0%, #2d91ff 1%, #004ea3 100%), -o-linear-gradient( top, #242b47 0%, #181d33 100%);
  background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(circle 232px at 56.15% 56.93%, #2d91ff 0%, #2d91ff 1%, #004ea3 100%), -webkit-linear-gradient( top, #242b47 0%, #181d33 100%);
  background-image: -moz-radial-gradient(circle 232px at 56.15% 56.93%, #2d91ff 0%, #2d91ff 1%, #004ea3 100%), -moz-linear-gradient(to top, #242b47 0%, #181d33 100%);
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle 232px at 56.15% 56.93%, #2d91ff 0%, #2d91ff 1%, #004ea3 100%), linear-gradient(to top, #242b47 0%, #181d33 100%);
}
```

```html
<button class='ticket'>ticket</button
```

linear-gradient срабатывает нормально а radial ничего не меняет